# nginx config for node + static files not catching

Tags: node.js, nginx, config, reverse-proxy, system-administration

Variations of this question have been asked before, but I just can't seem to get an `nginx` config to work...

I want to serve some static files for a react site eg 'index.html` at the root of the server.

```
http://www.lex.chat/
```

Instead files are being picked up from another app on the same server. This is nginx behavior to just pick some other random server when it can't find what it should, but confused why this state occurs,

The full config is below.
important points:

correct `server_name`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.lex.chat;
```

this is where I put all the built files inc index.html

```
root /mnt/ext250/web-apps/www.lex.chat/client;
```

and indeed checked it's all there:
`ls -la /mnt/ext250/web-apps/www.lex.chat/client/index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 staff 2057 Aug 27 22:28 /mnt/ext250/web-apps/www.lex.chat/client/index.html`

```
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
  }
```

so this should f**ng well work right?

By tailing the logs I can see another nginx app is catching and picking up the serving.
That server has a completely different `server_name` so I think it's just nginx "pick a random server" behavior, the main issue is not finding the right server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name minibot.bot-wiz.com;
```

Any other insights on the config below appreciated.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name www.lex.chat;
  root /mnt/ext250/web-apps/www.lex.chat/client;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/lexy.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/lexy.error.log;

  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
  }

  location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:55111;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Following is necessary for Websocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location /static {
    alias /mnt/ext250/web-apps/www.lex.chat/static;
  }

  # location /client {
  #   alias /mnt/ext250/web-apps/www.lex.chat/client;
  # }

  location /admin {
    alias /mnt/ext250/web-apps/www.lex.chat/admin;
  }

}
```

Going bald. Wish I could get back to writing code and not dealing with this :(

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercse `T`) to see the full configuration that Nginx is reading and ensure that your `server` block and `server_name` is present with no errors.

Comment: thanks, that's a useful flag, but it didn't solve the problem.